# Filter duplicate category after map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

After a dynamic display(fetch object) of my categories..
I would simply like to delete the duplicates but in a map () i do not understand how to do this ...

The problem is that map returns each categories in a single array

Should i do this in the jsx or in the function js ?

Thanks all

```
const SideMenu = () => {
  const [loading, products] = useFetchAllProducts();
  console.log("products", products);

  const loadCategory = (i) => {
    console.log(i);
    return i;
  };

  const filterCategory = (c) => {
    return c;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {products.map((link, index) => (
          <li key={link._id} onClick={() => loadCategory(index)}>
            {filterCategory(link.categoryProduct)}{" "}
          </li>
        ))}

        {/* Result =
              Masks
              Teddy
              Teddy
              Backpack
              Pencil case
              Pencil case
              Pencil case 
              ...
       */}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [a `Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) to pare down the products to unique categories:

```
const SideMenu = () => {
  const [loading, products] = useFetchAllProducts();

  // Make a set of unique categories...
  const categorySet = new Set(products.map((p) => p.categoryProduct));
  // ... and a sorted array from the set.
  const categories = Array.from(categorySet).sort();

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {categories.map((category, index) => (
          <li key={category}>{category}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```